# ASP.NET Freeze table header and columns

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to freeze the header row and first two columns of a table in ASP.NET. The table is populated at run time with different controls in each cell, some has TextBox controls, other labels and/or buttons.

After trying many different solutions, I found a [script](https://jaimonmathew.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/making-scrollable-tables-with-fixed-headers-updated-2/) that made this possible.

Now I am having two problems. Firstly, at some window sizes, the header row does not line up perfectly with the rest of the table, getting worse the further to the right you look. Secondly, when viewing the page in Firefox or Internet Explorer, the frozen row and columns are slow to update their position, resulting in them halting behind the actual scrolled table.

Is there are smarter way for me to be able to freeze the row and columns? It seems like a thing that has been done 100 times, and yet I cannot find a solution that works flawless for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an plug-in can fixed header and freeze column, maybe you can try. see the image:

[image: GridViewScroll]

The plug-in is placed on GitHub. Link: https://github.com/twlikol/GridViewScroll

There are two versions, you can try which kind is more easy to use.